# MATLAB: Histcounts for every slice of a 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, histogram

Is there a way the vectorize the following code? I would like to apply the histcounts function to every slice of a 3D matrix.

```
mat = rand(100,1,5);
[~,~,numRuns] = size(mat);
for i = 1 : numRuns
    [n(:,:,i), edges(:,:,i)] = histcounts(mat(:,:,i));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a separate histogram for every run, then leave it like that. Why would you even want to vectorize it? It is easy to read, and that's important. (You could vectorize it with `cellfun`, but in this case it would be complicated and not even faster.) If you want to increase the computation speed, use `parfor` instead of `for`.

But maybe you want a histogram of all the data. Then just do

```
[N,edges] = histcounts(mat);
```

and you got your overall histogram.